# Is it possible to a swagger parameter name have variables?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm documenting an API using swagger, and one of the parameters have a variable in it's name (eg: `param[VARIABLE]=value`). It will be sent in form, like this:

```
param[VAR1]=value1&param[VAR2]=value2
```

I think the parameter definition would be something like:

```
parameters:
  - name: 'param[{var}]'
    in: formData
    description: 'Parameter description'
    required: true
    type: string
```

Is it possible to implement this in swagger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not allowed in the swagger definition.  The UI and tooling don't prohibit the `[{}]` characters explicitly (that will change in 3.0) but passing variables is not supported.